# Sometimes to achieve [zen] you must destroy it

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

While doing a review for suggested edits I stumbled upon the [zen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zen) tag. This appears to be a collection of questions related to a C# [framework](https://github.com/dementeddevil/BarcodeRenderingFramework), a [drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal) theme, some related to a [vs-code-settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs-code-settings) theme and some which simply appear to be asking about best practices related to the Zen of Python.

Burnination criteria list:

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   Often the meaning depends completely on the other tags used in the question and often the title already provides the information. 
   In theory this could be disambiguated into many zen-related tags for each framework but I am not sure how informative many of these tags would be.
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   Sometimes. Often it appears as tangential as a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499885/hide-top-bar-in-visual-studio-code-zen-mode) about a theme in VSCode.
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   No.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   Definitely not, the meaning of the tag is exclusively dependent on the presence of other tags.

Comment: Also, at least one question about the AMD Zen processor architecture. Certainly too ambiguous to be useful. Also, the [excerpt history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7296007/revisions) for the tag is interesting.

Comment: A lot of the older questions seem to be related to [Zen Cart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_Cart). A couple about [a barcode rendering framework](https://github.com/dementeddevil/BarcodeRenderingFramework) too.

Comment: So are we supposed to meditate upon this burninate request first?

Comment: Bonus funny points for the question title when you know that "to achieve" comes from the french *achever* meaning "to mercy kill".

Comment: I retagged questions related to the `zen-of-python` with a newly created tag